# select multiple values from one condition (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, conditional-statements

I have a table which holds details of exams taken. Each exam entered into this table is entered as a pair of people i.e. two people per exam performed so you have per exam, two people. Each person has their own unique id for each exam taken but each pair has a value called partner_id which is the same for them both.

What I am trying to do is extract the partner_id values from that table in order to then be able to use those values to find the partners of a said person and show/echo onto the page the exam result details of every partner that person has had exam with.

What I have tried so far is:

```
$partner_ider = mysql_query("SELECT partner_id as value1 from exam WHERE Student_email='eating@gnomes.com'");
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($partner_ider);

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($partner_ider))
{
    echo $row1['value1'];
}
```

And this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from exam WHERE Student_email='beating@dead.com'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['partner_id'];
}
```

The result these would give is 2 for that email of which has two entries in the exam table, what I was looking for was 1, 2 which are the values of the two partner_ids for this email's exam records. When I change the email to someone else who only has one, it returns nothing.

What I would be looking to do with the result of 1, 2 is to use those values to select all other people except the original person(eating@gnomes.com) and show their details from out of that table.

What I'm asking for is how would I go about doing the above as I haven't done something like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both code snippets, you have at line 2 a mysql_fetch_array() which should not be there.
It fetches a row, puts it into $row1 and increments the internal pointer.

When you call mysql_fetch_array() in your while, it fetches the second record then the third etc. until all the rows have been processed.

You should, in both examples, remove the second line and try again.

```
$partner_ider = mysql_query("SELECT partner_id as value1 from exam WHERE Student_email='eating@gnomes.com'");
//$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($partner_ider);

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($partner_ider))
{
    echo $row1['value1'];
}
```

If your table structure is the following :

- id
- student_id
- student_name
- student_email
- student_whatever
- partner_id

The SQL query would look like

```
SELECT Student_email FROM exam WHERE partner_id IN (SELECT partner_id FROM exam WHERE student_Email = 'eating@gnomes.com') AND Student_email <> 'eating@gnomes.com';
```

But you should really split up your table. You have two entities (a student and an exam) and a joining table.

Student

- id
- name
- email

Exam

- id
- name
- (other exam data)

StudentGroup

- exam_id
- student_id
- group

Comment: Thank you, that worked. How would I go about using those values which for eating@gnomes.com would be 12 to pick out of the exam table the exam partners row to the point I could echo them out onto a page?

Comment: I'm getting an SQL error of Subquery returns more than 1 row. The table structure is as more or less how you hinted. What I am looking to do is to use 12 to select all fields of the two in this case exam partner's of eating@gnomes.com. One person could have many more partners, or just one in exam table. Hope that clears it up a bit more. Thanks for help so far.

Comment: Oh. I thought a student only had 1 partner. Then you probably have an exam_id field in your table. Do you want all the exam partners someone has had, or just his partners for a single exam ?

Comment: When I've tried using the PHP I'm getting "mysql_query(): Unable to save result set" and "mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given". I've also tried the SQL (had to correct the field names for both) for fetching someone's partner and getting a syntax error of "right syntax to use near '== 'eating@gnomes.com' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4". Fetching all pairs works as intended. EDIT to respond ot your reply: All partners they have had. Yes, exam_id field is AI so it is different for each person but the partner_id is what is the same for each different partner.

Comment: Yes, exam_id field is AI so it is different for each person but the partner_id is what is the same for each different **partnership**. Hope that makes sense. Do ask if your still not sure.

Comment: Ok. I think i'm getting it. :D I was mislead by the table name. I'll edit the last part of my answer to match this, but simply replacing the '=' of the subquery with a "IN" should do the trick (see answer).

Comment: My structure is not too distant to the structure your suggesting, I have a table which holds student data called student with a foreign key in the exam table being the Students_email. Will try your answer now.

Comment: It is working perfectly. With a bit of my own fine tuning, I've got it getting all fields and got it printing via PHP onto a page in a table format. Thank you so much for the help @Nicolas.